# can't instal myPreprocessors on python 3.11.4

Tags: python

When I try to install myPreprocessors in VS code:
pip install myPreprocessors

I get the following error messages
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement myPreprocessors (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for myPreprocessors

is there a fix? is that deprecated?

I tried re-starting the kernel, it didn't work.

Comment: This package doesn't appear to exist: https://pypi.org/search/?q=myPreprocessors I can't find any information about this package on Google. Can you explain more about what you're trying to install?

Comment: Can you share where you got instructions to do this? It feels to me like you're meant to replace "myPreprocessors" by the names of your actual proprocessors, like maybe black, flake8 or somesuch.